# What level of role / user should be created for executing stored procedure in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

What level of role / user should be created for executing stored procedure in SQL Azure ?

As I spin up a SQL Azure PaaS instance I create a Admin user by default.

Now within this database - I plan to create stored procedures. What level of role / user should I create and where - to give explicit permissions to just this role for the stored procedures?

Comment: Depends, does the user/role need to execute all SP's on the database, just ones on a specific schema, only very certain ones?

Answer (score 1):

Create logins in the master database.

```
CREATE LOGIN Mary WITH PASSWORD = '<strong_password>';
```

Create user on the database you want to execute stored procedures.

```
CREATE USER Mary FROM LOGIN Mary;
```

You can create a role on your in the database.

```
CREATE ROLE proc_executor
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO proc_executor
GO
```

And then you can add database users to that role.

```
ALTER ROLE proc_executor ADD MEMBER Mary;
```